# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

Tags: service, ip, localhost, http-status-code-400

I am trying to get result from my WebService with name Service1.svc

I get success result by address
http://localhost:49534/Service1.svc

IP address of my computer is 192.168.1.134
Why do I get `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname by address HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid`by address http://192.168.1.134:49534/Service1.svc

By address http://127.0.0.1:49534/Service1.svc same error

In IIS Manager I add binding in Default Web Site with port 49534 and IP address 192.168.1.134

Comment: What server are using to deal with the request? It looks like it's not configured to deal with requests using an IP address in place of a hostname.

Comment: @Alex, I am using IIS server. My OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

open your web site properties, locate the Ip Address and near its there is the advanced, "multiple identities for this web site". There you need ether to add all income to this site with a star: "*", ether place the names you like to work with.

Comment: i can't find this option in my iis manager, my os is windows 10.